# selectOneMenu filter by various columns and not just the label

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

Looking at the "Advanced" example here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml, I was able to have two columns in each of the options in my `oneMenu`, but the filtering only happens on the item's label.

What I would like to be able to do is filter by either of the columns (unlike the example, both my columns contain only text, so they are filterable). Is this customization possible?

Adding `filter="true"` to either of the `<p:column>`s doesn't seem to have any effect while the utility: `filterFunction` to write custom filtering rules seems to operate only on the label also!

```
<p:outputLabel for="advanced" value="Advanced:"  />
<p:selectOneMenu id="advanced" value="#{selectOneMenuView.theme}" converter="themeConverter" panelStyle="width:180px"
                         effect="fade" var="t" style="width:160px" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
  <f:selectItems value="#{selectOneMenuView.themes}" var="theme" itemLabel="#{theme.displayName}" itemValue="#{theme}" />
  <p:column style="width:10%">
    <h:outputText styleClass="ui-theme ui-theme-#{t.name}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{t.displayName}" />
  </p:column>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, sorry, this is not possible with the selectOneMenu. You can add a filterFunction, but in that function you can only filter client-side on the label.

As an alternative, you can use the [PrimeFaces AutoComplete](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml) which can search server side on anything you want and also display custom content.

Comment: It appears that the `autocomplete` requires us to provide the filtering options thru the `completeMethod` attribute? Also it does not seem to support pure client-side filtering (a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=842) was raised, but was closed with the status: "wont-fix").

Comment: Yes.. Adnd Client-side autocomplete is illogical since it does not provide a performance advantage over the selectonemenu with filtering

Comment: Sorry, I wrote client-side in my answer which should have been server-side. Corrected it (It was late ;-))

Answer (score 0):

you can do it, if you write `<f:selectItems value="#{estadoParque.vehiculos}" var="v" itemValue="#{v}" itemLabel="#{v.placa} - #{v.marca}"/>`

adding the same elements of the columns `itemLabel="#{v.placa} - #{v.marca}"`

```
<p:column headerText="Placa">
                            <h:outputText value="#{t.placa}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Marca">
                            <h:outputText value="#{t.marca}" />
                        </p:column>
```

and your filter will be like `filterMatchMode="contains"`

it works!!